# Can't figure out why PHP function isn't getting executed

Tags: php, function

In a PHP script that uploads a file and inserts some form data into a database, the function that does the DB insert isn't being called. Take a look at the code below. As you can see, I've got logging statements all over the code to track what's going on. You'll see that the line `$log->lwrite('Successfully moved the file to the destination folder.');` is getting written to the log file, but nothing else is getting written to the log file after that, including the line `$log->lwrite('$inserted: ' . $inserted);`.

In the jQuery Form plugin that calls this, the upload progress is showing properly and gets to 100% and the file is getting uploaded, but none of the code in the complete part of the callback executes.

Please take a look. I can't see what I'm missing here.

**Update Below**

Here is my PHP script:

```
require ('logging.php');
$log = new Logging();

$fileName = basename($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
$targetPath = '../media/' . $fileName;
$title = $_POST['sermonTitle'];
$speaker = $_POST['speakerName'];
$date = $_POST['sermonDate'];

$log->lwrite('file name: ' . $fileName . ', title: ' . $title . ', speaker: ' . $speaker . ', date: ' . $date);

if ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['type'] === 'audio/mp3') {
    $log->lwrite('Correct file type.');
    if (file_exists($targetPath)) {
        $log->lwrite('File already exists.');
        // File with the selected name already exists on the server
        exit ('exists');
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'],$targetPath)) {
            $log->lwrite('Successfully moved the file to the destination folder.');

            $inserted = AddSermonToDb();

            $log->lwrite('$inserted: ' . $inserted);

            if ($inserted == true) {
                $log->lwrite('Added the sermon to the DB.');
                exit ('success');
            } else {
                $log->lwrite('Failed to add the sermon to the DB.');
                exit ('insertFail');
            }

        } else {
            $log->lwrite('Couldn\'t upload the file.');
            // Problem uploading the file or moving it to the destination folder
            exit ('uploadFail');
        }
    }
} else {
    $log->lwrite('Invalid file type.');
    exit ('invalidType');
}

function AddSermonToDb() {

    $log->lwrite('In AddSermonToDb function');

    // Connect to the database
    //require_once([path to connection script]);

    $query = "INSERT INTO sermons (sermonMp3FileName, sermonTitle, sermonSpeaker, sermonDate)
            VALUES ('$fileName', '$title', '$speaker', '$date')";

    $log->lwrite('$query: ' . $query);

    $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    $log->lwrite('$result: ' . $result);

    mysqli_close($dbc);

    if ($result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's the jQuery Form plugin script

```
// Reset validation and progress elements
var percentVal = '0%';
$('.statusBar').width(percentVal);
$('.percent').html(percentVal);

$('#frmSermonUpload').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        var formValid;

        if (!ValidateUploadForm()) {
            formValid = false;
        } else {
            formValid = true;
        }

        if (!formValid) {
            return false;
        }

    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';

        $('.statusBar').width(percentVal)
        $('.percent').html(percentVal);    
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {

        if (xhr.responseText === 'success') {
            $('.statusBar').width('100%');
            $('.percent').html('100%');
            $('#status').html('Successfully uploaded the sermon.<br>Successfully added the sermon to the database.').addClass('successUpload');

            ClearForm();

        } else if (xhr.responseText === 'uploadFail') {
            $('#status').html('There was a problem uploading the file. Try again.<br>If the problem persists, contact the system administrator.').addClass('errorUpload');
        } else if (xhr.responseText === 'exists') {
            $('#status').html('A file with that name already exists on the server.').addClass('errorUpload');
        } else if (xhr.responseText === 'insertFail') {
            $('#status').html('The file was uploaded, but there was a problem inserting the information into the database.').addClass('errorUpload');
        } else if (xhr.responseText === 'invalidType') {
            $('#status').html('Invalid file type. Only audio files with the extention "mp3" are allowed.').addClass('errorUpload');
        }
    }
}); // End Upload Status Bar
```

Thanks for anyone's help.

**UPDATE**

I'm embarrassed to admit that a few of you were right in pointing out that I wasn't passing the variables to the function.

Further, no, I didn't check the PHP error log (I can't believe I'm admitting all of this stuff that should have been so obvious!).

So, I added the variables to the function call and checked the PHP error log, where I found the line `Call to a member function lwrite() on a non-object in /home3/fbcglenw/public_html/scripts/sermonUpload.php on line 44`, which is the first line calling $log in the function.

I thought the function would be able to "see" the $log object, so I tried adding $log to the function call and the variables in the function definition, but that didn't change the error.

**Update #2**
I'm not sure (that's why I'm here asking for help), but it seems this is turning out to be a scope issue, but if the $log object is right at the beginning of the php script, I would have thought that any function in that script should be able to "see" that $log object...

Comment: Maybe `AddSermonToDb()` produces a fatal error that halts the entire code. Any error messages in the PHP error logs?

Comment: Any errors have occured? insert line: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: you have checked for errors in the error log, right?

Answer (score 1):

$fileName     $title     $speaker    $date is null

you need pass value like AddSermonToDb($fileName, $title,$speaker,$date)

```
function AddSermonToDb() {

$log->lwrite('In AddSermonToDb function');

// Connect to the database
//require_once([path to connection script]);

$query = "INSERT INTO sermons (sermonMp3FileName, sermonTitle, sermonSpeaker, sermonDate)
        VALUES ('$fileName', '$title', '$speaker', '$date')";
.....
```

and

```
//if you use jquery add 
$(function(){     
 //jquery code

})
```

Comment: Yes, I have that in my js script - just excluded it as an assumed given... Thanks, though.

Comment: @eventide: if value of $fileName, $title,$speaker,$date is answer,pls tick

Comment: Although I was missing passing the variables to the function, unfortunately no, the issue really hasn't been resolved. I had to move on with this because I needed to get this project done ASAP, so I just removed the offending lines (the $log lines **only** in the function were causing the error).

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like it's erroring out here:

```
$inserted = AddSermonToDb();
```

To be sure, just write a simple try/catch to handle the error in a predictable way.

Answer (score 0):

The variables $fileName, $title $speaker and $date in your SQL query

```
INSERT INTO sermons (sermonMp3FileName, sermonTitle, sermonSpeaker, sermonDate)
        VALUES ('$fileName', '$title', '$speaker', '$date')
```

are defined outside the functions scope.  As they don't exist in the function they will either be errorring if warnings are turned on, or null if they are turned off.

This could cause your query to have unexpected results and could be causing a fatal error which will halt your code execution and prevent any further logs